# Standardizing Sharpe Ratio or not when standardizing Features

Tags: sharpe-ratio, machine-learning

I am currently trying to check the Feature Autocorrelation for a Trend Strategy. I am using XGBoost for that purpose. In addition I work with SHAP.

In the first run I realized that without Standardization of the Mean Return and Volatility SHAP will give those two Features a importance that high, so that SHAP isn't able to check the Autocorrelation Features. Now I standardized the Mean return by subtracting the mean of the portfolio to every cell. I standardized the Vola by diving the previous calculated value by the Vola of the Portfolio and multipliying by 0.015.

I am checking the Autocorrelation by the Risk-Adjusted return (Sharpe Ratio) my question is now: Do I need to use the Standardized Values for Sharpe Ratio or the NOT standardized Values?

Comment: Just to be clear - could you list exactly the features you are using (that are relevant to this question), and the transformations/standardizations you apply?

Comment: The standardization is like mentioned above: I use the pre standardized returns and subtract the average return (for the whole timeframe)  for each column. In the second step I divide the new value by the standard deviation (for the whole timeframe) and multiply it by 0.015 to get the annualized standard deviation by that.

The other Features that I am using are Lag-1 Autocorrelations of my investments strategy over different frequenzies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. For this solution you need to use the standardized data.